# MySQL-Python with PyPy

Tags: installation, mysql-python, pypy

**MySQL-Python (MySQLdb) is [known to work with PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/mysql-python). How *do* you make it work?**

I tried [downloading it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) and installing:

```
C:\dev\Installs\MySQL-python\MySQL-python-1.2.3>pypy setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\dev\Installs\MySQL-python\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then I tried to download the [ctypes implementation](https://github.com/quora/mysql-ctypes) which seemed to have installed ok, however trying to use it gave:

```
  ...
  File "C:\pypy-1.7\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: Can't find a libmysqlclient
```

I'm at a loss at this point. How do I make it work

Comment: About your first error: take a look at all the paths in site.cfg and setup.cfg for mysqldb.  Some of them have incorrect defaults ("(x86)" present in windows 32bit, wrong paths etc).  That, or the wrong version of mysql.  If you get it working definitely let me know how cause as far as I know, pypy + MySQLdb still doesn't work out of the box on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second error with mysql-ctypes, the answer is that the line

```
ctypes.util.find_library('mysqlclient')
```

can't find the library on windows.  Changing it to:

```
ctypes.util.find_library('mysqlclient.lib')
```

works on my system - but that only gets you to the next error (windows error 193) on my system.

Answer (score 1):

you're right, the original MySQLdb is known to not work on PyPy.

I never tried to install mysql-ctypes on a windows maschine as I do not have one, but do you have libmysqlclient installed in your PATH?

If so, you may try my (sadly not yet merged) fork on https://github.com/EnTeQuAk/mysql-ctypes which has support for a bit more versions of libmysqlclient.

Comment: I tried your fork and unfortunately I get the same error. I tried googling about this `libmysqlclient` but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had no issues with the `MySQLdb` package in `pypy` after installing it using `pip`.

You can find instructions for installing `pip` for `pypy` in the second section of the following link: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#installing-pypy

Once you have `pip` installed, it's just a matter of running

```
pip install MySQL-python
```